# SQL DataTime affected by Server new time

Tags: sql-server-2008, timezone, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a server in production, this is why i want to ask before experimenting, that is set tu -6 GMT. I need to have it configured to -5GMT with Daylight Saving. (which i think automatically makes the GMT go to -4 in summer time).

I have millions of records that were inserted when my server was -6 (which still is). I recall thou that time in SQL is inserted using UTC (which is my understanding is standard to whatever timezone you are working at. SQL would do the calculation for you based on your Console Management time). Correct me if i am wrong.

Would changing my server time would affect in any way my datetimes in sql?

Thanks so much.

Comment: "I recall thou that time in SQL is inserted using UTC" - that's up to your application and the database. We'd need to know more information. I'm sure SQL and applications *can* be written in a way which causes them to break if you change time zone - but equally they can be written not to.

Comment: SQL Server stores thy time in whatever format thou tellest it to. It doesn't automatically switch to UTC.

Comment: I understand that. But i think by default it comes UTC.